# google api with javascript. get birthday and gender

Tags: javascript, google-api

I think it must be simple but couldnt find an example.
I'm using the basic google signin example. with header tags (including birthday scope):

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read" />
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxx my id xxx" />
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

and a defualt login button in the html body:

```
<div id="gsignin" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

and js:

```
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log(googleUser);
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
        g_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  }
```

All this works just fine, user is asked to grant permissions. and i get the general profile info. but i'm not sure how to obtain the birthday date, is it somehow in the returned object? do i need another call to the api?
I've seen lots of examples about using scopes but couldn't find **how to actually read the data**(birthday date)... same thing for gender, don't think there is a special scope for that, i guess it should be part of the basic profile info(?)
Thanks in advance

**edit:** just to clarify, i know i'm using the right scope. i don't know how to read the data. for example, after user authenticated - profile.getEmail() will return the email. what would return the birthday?

Comment: The birthday is not always available in the JSON. Only users who share their birth-date have the birthday property.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask about scope but the answer is the same.

Comment: thanks. can you please elaborate. assume it is public will i find it in profile.getBirthday() ? or do i need to make another call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GoogleUser.getBasicProfile()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) Get the user's basic profile information.

> Returns
>  A gapi.auth2.BasicProfile object. You can retrieve this
>   object's properties with the following methods: 
> BasicProfile.getId()
>   BasicProfile.getName()
>  BasicProfile.getImageUrl()
>   BasicProfile.getEmail()

This method does not return birthday. The only way I know of to get birthday back would be to use [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#request-body) from the google+ api.

Comment: do I need to init another/different gapi object using another library? 
I have a "live" gapi object, i guess it's created by the included script https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js  but if i try `gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {...});` i get js error "Cannot read property 'load' of undefined"

Comment: Yup you will need a different service a google+ api service https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/blob/master/index.html  I am not a javaScript expert found you that though its the official sample project.

Comment: after adding Google+ api in the api manager and after adding ref to https://apis.google.com/js/client.js I can now call `gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {...});` 
but I'm still not getting the birthday in the response although I made sure it is public (testing on my own account). also it's strange that I now use both client.js and platform.js and i guess there are 2 "live" gapi objects. don't think this is the intended implementation...

Comment: got it to work. my public settings were not correct. 
still not clear as to these 2 sign in options and 2 script references, does Google+ sign in supposed to replace Google sign in